# How to check if an object is a KeyboardEvent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to have a function that accepts event as a parameter and checks if valid event object is passed.

```
function doSomething(e){
  if(e is a keyboard event){
   // Proceed
  } else {
    console.log('Error: e is not a KeyboardEvent');
  }
}
```

`typeof e` just returns `object`. But debug console clearly shows *KeyboardEvent*, so it must be readable somehow.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Vanilla JS

as simple as that with the `instanceof` operator:

```
if (e instanceof KeyboardEvent){
  // it is a keyboard event!
}
```

Explainations from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) :

> The `instanceof` operator tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor.

Note that this operator can be messy when dealing with multiple (i)frame/windows because they have different context and different builtins. but in the same window/frame, it's not a problem.

**Example :**

```js
document.querySelector("#foo").addEventListener("keydown", (event)=>{
  console.log("event instanceof KeyboardEvent : ",event instanceof KeyboardEvent);
});
```

```html
<label for="foo">edit input to check event type</label>
<input type="text" id="foo">
```

### jQuery

jQuery wraps native events with its own implementation :

> jQuery's event system normalizes the event object according to W3C standards. The event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler (no checks for window.event required). It normalizes the target, relatedTarget, which, metaKey and pageX/Y properties and provides both stopPropagation() and preventDefault() methods.

[source](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Event)

But Note that the native event is still accessible via `event.originalEvent`. And you can still test `event.type` (`event.type==="keyup" || event.type==="keydown" || event.type === "keypress"`).

**Example :**

```js
$("#foo").on("keyup", (jqEvent) => {
  console.log("jqEvent instanceof KeyboardEvent : ", jqEvent instanceof KeyboardEvent); //false
  console.log("jqEvent.originalEvent instanceof KeyboardEvent : ", jqEvent.originalEvent instanceof KeyboardEvent); //true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="foo">edit input to check event type</label>
<input type="text" id="foo">
```

Comment: In Chrome when I put `console.log(e instanceof InputEvent)` in my `input` event handler, it returns `false`. Any ideas why?

Comment: I found out it's because the YUI rich text editor widget is using custom events.

Comment: But, when you try to type check the event, this won't be helpful. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19qpread/14/). The type of the incoming event is `Object` (which is acceptable), but not `KeyboardEvent` (which is confusing). Any idea why?

Comment: @RomeoSierra Because jQuery wraps native events with its own event type. You can test `jqEvent.originalEvent` though.

Comment: @RomeoSierra I added a jQuery section to my answer

Comment: @n00dl3 Prompt response! (y). By the time you added it, I already have tested your point in the jsfiddle I have already added in the comment! :) Thanks a bunch for the knowledge you shared! :)

Answer (score 3):

This would work for your case.

Be careful with `input-event` it is not an instance of KeyboardEvent.

```js
function testEventType(e){
 console.log(e.type, e instanceof KeyboardEvent);
}

document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener('keypress', testEventType);
document.querySelector("#test").addEventListener('input', testEventType);
```

```html
<input id="test"/>
```

Comment: DomeTune, thanks for the warning. Can an `input` be generated by keyboard?

Comment: @Alph.Dev Yes `KeyboardEvent` inherits from `InputEvent`
`Event`<---`InputEvent`<---`KeyboardEvent`. so `KeyboardEvent`s are `InputEvent`s.

Comment: @Alph.Dev a n00dl3 allready pointed out you can check for `InputEvent`, the Event includes ShortCuts as well. `CTRL+V`, `CTRL+X`, ...

Answer (score 1):

try this `if(e.type == 'keypress')`

```
function doSomething(e){
  if(e.type == 'keypress'){
   // Proceed
  } else {
    console.log('Error: e is not a KeyboardEvent');
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I can always use `(e.type == 'keypress' || e.type == 'keydown' || e.type == 'keyup')`, but that is messy. I'm trying to find a way to use `KeyboardEvent` key word.